# Создать триггеры MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Как создать триггер?
Триггер: 
Расход бензина за рейс не должен превышать 100 литров.

[image: Диаграмма]

Comment: Для решения задачи триггер не нужен. Достаточно CHECK constraint.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь CHECK CONSTRAINT. [Ссылка на документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  CHECK (c1 <> c2),
  c1 INT CHECK (c1 > 10),
  c2 INT CONSTRAINT c2_positive CHECK (c2 > 0),
  c3 INT CHECK (c3 < 100),
  CONSTRAINT c1_nonzero CHECK (c1 <> 0),
  CHECK (c1 > c3)
);
```